# How to display fields of a M2M relation

Tags: python, django, m2m

I have this Django model:

```
#encoding:utf-8
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import admin

# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, related_name='user')
    follows = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='follows', symmetrical=False, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatar', blank=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)

admin.site.register(Profile)

admin.autodiscover()
```

Then, I have this view:

```
def profile(request, user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=user_id)
    return render_to_response('user_view.html', {'user':user,})
```

Now, in `user_view.html` I display the 'User' data (username, avatar, website, etc):

```
{{user.user_id}}
{{user.user}}
{{user.website}}
{{user.avatar.url}}
```

But, also I need to display the username, avatar and website of the users I follow. I did this:

```
{% for element in user.follows.all %}
    <a href="{{element.website}}">{{element.user}}</a>
    <img src="{{element.avatar.url}} />
{% endfor %}
```

But, instead of display the user's data, it shows this:

```
<django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager object at 0x022F34F0>
```

But if I do this:

```
{% for element in user.follows.all %}
    <p>{{element}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

It shows perfectly the user's name, but I still cannot display the website or the avatar. How can I do this?

Comment: Please edit your code to show what you actually tried. `user_data` is used later in your question but it is not shown where it is declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would try

```
{% for element in user_data.follows.all %}
    <p>{{element.username}}</p>
    <p>{{element.profile.website}}</p>
    <p>{{element.profile.avatar}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

**element** is an instance of **User** and not an instance of **Profile**.
But you can still retrieve the associated **Profile** instance by writing

```
element.profile
```

because it's a One-To-One relationship (OneToOneField or ForeignKey(unique=True))

Comment: You are right! That was my error. I just change my model from `follows = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='follows', symmetrical=False, blank=True)` to `follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='follows', symmetrical=False, blank=True)` it works perfectly now. Thanks a lot!